# Nvidia GPG Error The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, updates, cuda

Got this error while trying to update cuda

```
Err:1 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC

W: GPG error: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 InRelease:
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A4B469963BF863CC 
E: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 InRelease' is not signed. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 10):

solved with this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub

sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

Comment: Where did you find those URLs?

Comment: If your base image is ubuntu 18 then adding these two as RUN statements before your apt-get update solves the issues. Very handy with tensorflow official docker image build to fix the issues.